# jquery calculate total with quantity and steps

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help!
I need a jquery script to calculate total:
I need 1 input field for quantity.
If the quantity is:
between 1 and 60, the price is 750,
between 61 and 90, the price is 850,
between 91 and 120, the price is 995,
I also need to add new row with quantity input field
and I need to calculate the total price of all.
I have already tried but don't know how to do it.

Thanks.
I have tried the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function miaFunzione() {
        $("#Container").append("<li><input type='text' class='qty' value='' placeholder='superfice' /> <a onclick='miaFunzione()'>aggiungi [+]</a></li>");

        var totale = 0;

        $("#Container li").each(function () {
            var qty = new Number($(this).children('.qty').val());

            if (qty <= 60) {
                prezzo = 750;
            }else if (qty >= 61 && qty <= 90){
                prezzo = 850;
            }else if (qty >= 91 && qty <= 120){
                prezzo = 995;
            };

            totale = totale + prezzo;

        });

        $("#totMoney").html(totale);
    }
</script>
```

this is the html code

```
<ul id="Container">
    <li>
        <input type="text" value="" class="qty" placeholder="superfice" /><a onclick="miaFunzione()">aggiungi [+]</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<br />

TOTALE COSTO: € <strong id="totMoney">0</strong>
```

Comment: What is your problem, Is there any problem faced by you?

Comment: You should really bind with on() instead of using the inline bindings.  But as @Frayne Konok asked, what issue are you having?  What errors are you seeing?

Comment: Create an onchange event for qty and then get the total, don't get the total when you create a new row.

Comment: i don't know if this code is right, because it don't run, and i don't know how to do this, i hope you can help me to write the right code,i need to add many row, and the total of all row, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this jsfiddle I made for you https://jsfiddle.net/n5zoyxq3/

```
function miaFunzione() {
    $("#Container").append("<li><input type='text' class='qty' value='' placeholder='superfice' /> <a onclick='miaFunzione()'>aggiungi [+]</a></li>");

    var totale = 0;
    var prezzo = 0;

    $("#Container li").each(function () {
        var qty = parseFloat($(this).children('.qty').val());
    if(qty > 0) {
      if (qty <= 60) {
        prezzo = 750;
      }else if (qty >= 61 && qty <= 90){
        prezzo = 850;
      }else if (qty >= 91 && qty <= 120){
        prezzo = 995;
      };
    }

        totale = totale + prezzo;
        prezzo = 0;

    });

    $("#totMoney").html(totale);
}
```

I've changed the line "var qty = new Number($(this).children('.qty').val());" to 
"var qty = parseFloat($(this).children('.qty').val());" just to avoid error in case '.qty' has no numeric value.

Below that line I added an "if" to check if var qty has value because your user can add various inputs without value.

After assigning the prezzo to totale I changed prezzo to "0" so in the next loop prezzo will start with value zero.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('keyup','li > .qty',function(){
        var totale = 0;

        $("#Container li .qty").each(function () {
            var qty = parseFloat($(this).val());

            if (qty <= 60) {
                prezzo = 750;
            }else if (qty >= 61 && qty <= 90){
                prezzo = 850;
            }else if (qty >= 91 && qty <= 120){
                prezzo = 995;
            }

            totale +=  qty + prezzo;

        });

        $("#totMoney").html(totale);
    }); 
    $('body').on('click','li > a',function(){
      $("#Container").append("<li><input type='text' class='qty' value='' placeholder='superfice' /> <a>aggiungi [+]</a></li>");

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="Container">
    <li>
        <input type="text" value="" class="qty" placeholder="superfice" /><a>aggiungi [+]</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<br />

TOTALE COSTO: € <strong id="totMoney">0</strong>
```